# Name of electric force

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation

during a lab experiment, i noticed that a metal ball has a much harder time rolling on metal rails when their is a current passing through it and the rails. I was wondering why and if there was a name for this force. Does the fact that a current passes "pull " the balls towards the rails and increases friction?
Thanks

Comment: Is the ball made from magnetic material? If it isn't, then the ball should actually accelerate in one direction (well... it actually depends how the rails are being powered).

Comment: The ball is made of steel

Comment: Sounds like the ball gets magnetized by the current and sticks to the (also magnetic?) rails?

Comment: Ok, this seems to make sense. But just so im clear, if you pass current directly through a ferromagnetic material will that magnetize it?

Comment: Yes, a strong current passing trough a ferromagnetic material will cause a magnetization. Whether the current passes trough the magnetic material itself or trough a non-magnetic wire near it, like in an electromagnet, makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, its quite like the slider moving on parallel rails. The extra 'force' you observe is the Lorentz drag force on the slider(idlxB).It opposes the motion of the slider,so as to oppose the change in flux through the circuit. You can look it up on the net as well.But im pretty sure its effectively the same in case of the ball.

Comment: Hello, i do not believe it is the lorentz force as there is no magnetic field with enough magnitude to cause such a big change in final speed of the ball ( the one induced by the rails is not nearly big enough to have this effect) this being said, do you have any other ideas on what could cause this resistive force?