# Magnetizing a ferromagnetic material.

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

if i pass a DC current directly through iron or steel or something ferromagnetic, Would that magnetize that material? And would it be magnetized permanently?

Another question, does anyone know what the US navy's railgun is made of (just the rails and projectile)

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265765/name-of-electric-force

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this question is yes.

As you know that when you pass current from any wire it produces magnetic field.  Outside of wire this field decreases as $\frac{1}{r}$ (if the wire is infinite long). However the field inside wire will increases linearly with distance $r$ from wire center. Also the field is poloidal i.e. circulating around circumference of wire.

$B=\frac {\mu_0\mu_r Ir}{4\pi R^2}$

To magnetize any ferromagnetic material with appreciable residual magnetic field one need to first put it in saturation magnetic field for iron it is ~2 tesla. Iron's relative permeability is 10000 to 200000 and it drops to ~1 near saturation. Hence you can magnetize it but with large amount of current (100s of amps.). In this process you have to take care of cooling because high current can increase the temperature of the wire which can destroy the ferromagnetic properties of the wire.